# How to Upload to SharePoint using a memory stream? Using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom, file-upload, c-sharp

I am creating a method to `UploadDocument_FromStream()` method which has one parameter -- `Stream file`.

I am having trouble trying to keep my SharePoint connection open to allow me to upload my `Stream file` to SharePoint. I think the issue is due to the fact that I am executing a query then trying to upload to SharePoint.

Is this the best way to handle Uploading to SharePoint with a `MemoryStream`?

---

#### UploadDocument_FromStream()

```
public void UploadDocument_FromStream(Stream file)
    {
        using (var clientContext = OpenConnectionToSharePoint())
        {
            if (file == null) throw new Exception("Stream cannot be null");

            using (clientContext)
            {
                var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
                clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, "/shared documents/test.pdf", file, true);
            }
     }
```

Also should note - that I am using `SharePoint.Client.dll` or CSOM approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void UploadDocument_FromStream(Stream file, string fileName)
    {
        using (var clientContext = OpenConnectionToSharePoint())
        {
            var webContext = clientContext.Web.Context;

            if (file == null) throw new Exception("Stream cannot be null");
            if (webContext.HasPendingRequest) webContext.ExecuteQuery();

            var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(SharePointRoot);
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            var fileUrl = Path.Combine(list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fileName);

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(
                clientContext, fileUrl, file, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: may be, another option is FileCreationInformation.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is FileCreationInformation...

```
function File Upload(ClientContext ctx, string folderRelativeUrl, string fileName, Stream data)
{
    var ci = new FileCreationInformation()
    {
        ContentStream = fs.Value,
        Overwrite = true,
        Url = folderRelativeUrl + "/" + fileName
    };
    var newFile = destinationInfo.Folder.Files.Add(ci);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    return newFile;
}
```

Comment: where are you getting the value of fs?